# Servlet is not displaying the data fetched from an html page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am new to Web Development in java, and just started with servlets with a project "Welcome Servlet". It has 3 files , 1. ColServlet.java in default package. 2. index.html in WebContent folder. 3. web.xml in WEB-INF folder. 
ColServlet.java is :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
   public class ColServlet extends HttpServlet
{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
                throws ServletException, IOException  

 {  
String colname =  request.getParameter("col"); 
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter info = response.getWriter();

info.println("The color is: ");
info.println(" <HTML>\n" +
            "<HEAD><TITLE>Hello WWW</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
            "<BODY>\n" +
            "<H1>Hello WWW</H1>\n" +
            "<h1>"+colname+"</h1>"+
            "</BODY></HTML>");
info.close();
}
}
```

index.html file is :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Select Color</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="/ColServlet">
            Select the color:
            <select name="col" size="3">
                <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                <option value="orange">Orange</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml file is :

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ColServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ColServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

NOW :  the problem is whenever i select any color, next page doesn't show the selected one.

Comment: M using Eclipse and Tomcat 7.0

Comment: What info is shown in the the next page?

Comment: In address bar : "http://localhost:8080/ColServlet?col=orange"
On Webpage : 
HTTP Status 404 - /ColServlet

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /ColServlet

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52

Comment: If you have a context path, the `action` attribute should have a value of `ColServlet` instead of `/ColServlet`. Or better yet, with EL, `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ColServlet`. (These two are completely different, you can look up what each one does.)

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome, and the webpage says :                         HTTP Status 404 - /Welcome_Servlet/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/ColServlet

type Status report

message /Welcome_Servlet/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/ColServlet

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [@SotiriosDelimanolis' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210198/servlet-is-not-displaying-the-data-fetched-from-an-html-page#comment33720810_22210198), you should change the action path in your `<form>` to also use the context path of the application. You should update this line in your index.html file:

```html
<form method="GET" action="<applicationName>/ColServlet">
```

Where `<applicationName>` is the name of your web application, which is usually the name of your web project e.g. "WelcomeServet" (without quotes).

If you happen to use a JSP file instead (which can be as easy as renaming index.html to index.jsp), then update this line to:

```html
<form method="GET" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ColServlet">
```